# Read file from subfolder of application installation folder

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, file-handling

I have to read the text content from an `.txt` file, this file is located in app installed folder, in a subfolder, according to [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185401.aspx), I am doing it like this:

```
 private async void readMyFile()
    {
        // Get the app's installation folder.
        StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        // Get a file from a subfolder of the current folder by providing a relative path.
        string txtFileName = @"\myfolder\myfile.txt";

        try
        {
            //here my file exists and I get file path
            StorageFile txtfile = await appFolder.GetFileAsync(txtFileName);
            Debug.WriteLine("ok file found: " + txtfile.Path);

            //here I get the error
            string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(txtfile);
            Debug.WriteLine("Txt is: " + text);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

the error is:

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
exception file not found: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Smadshop.MainPage.<testExistsFile>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Have to notice that if I use the file without subfolder everything is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it in other way, using `URI` :

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///file.txt");
```

So in your case it will be:

```
StorageFile txtfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///myfolder/myfile.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`@"\myfolder\myfile.txt";`  if its a network path should be `@"\\myfolder\myfile.txt";`  If its a local file it needs a drive letter ie.`@"c:\myfolder\myfile.txt";`

However the documentation for GetFileAsync shows a file in a subfolder would be `@"myfolder\myfile.txt"`

When you use a filename without a subfolder it will look in the current folder.

Comment: @VasileDoe The documentation for `GetFileAsync` shows a file in a subfolder would be `@"myfolder\myfile.txt"`

Comment: yep, that's it - I'll change your answer as the right one if you edit it according to this comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
string txtFileName = @".\myfolder\myfile.txt";
```

The dot in the filename represents the current folder. In you want to specify using relative paths, then `@"\myfolder\myfile.txt"` is not correct.

Comment: Nitpick: `@"\myfolder\myfile.txt"` is relative path too, just from the root of the device... May work on desktop .Net (not UWP as likely in OP case) apps when looking from root of current drive.

Comment: ok, maybe is not correct but I can get the file using  `StorageFile txtfile = await appFolder.GetFileAsync(txtFileName);`  but your solution is saying me  `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: An item cannot be found with the specified name (.\myfolder\myfile.txt).

Additional information: The parameter is incorrect`

Answer (score 0):

[GetFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfileasync.aspx) will take relative path in form `folder/fileName`. You can also get folder first and than file or use [GetItemAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.storagefolder.getitemasync.aspx)

```
StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
// Get a file from a subfolder of the current folder
// by providing a relative path.
string image = @"Assets\Logo.scale-100.png";
var logoImage = await appFolder.GetFileAsync(image);
```